# How to run an R script in python and assign the dataframe to a python variable?

Tags: python, r, dataframe

I was wondering if anyone can help me with this. I need to run an R script within python and have the final data frame in the script be assigned to a variable in python. The R script returns a single data frame, so I would like to assign that data frame to the a python variable, but I want to avoid having to save the data frame somewhere and then have to read it in again from somewhere else, I have tried  this:

```
import subprocess
df = subprocess.call("/usr/bin/Rscript ~/myfolderwithscript/example_script.R", shell=True)
```

But `df` is empty, any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: how are you expecting this to work? did you print the dataframe to the console? Any how... google up rpy2. That should get you what you need.

Comment: rpy2 is a good solution, but honestly i would save the data frame to a external file and then read the external file in python. Why do you want to avoid that approach?

Comment: @TomasCapretto I wanted to avoid making the directory more messy, and I also wanted to be able to call a script, which calls another scripts rather than initially calling 2 scripts at the start...

Comment: But if the data frame is created in R and then used in Python you can 1. Create folder, 2. Save data frame in a convenient format, 3. Read data in Python and 4. Delete folder from Python. Then, you don't need to worry about the extra messiness of the directory.